# Python format array list into string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to take an array list and attach it to a string.

Python 2.7.10, Windows 10

The list is loaded from a mySQL table and the output is this:

```
skuArray = [('000381001238',) ('000381001238',) ('000381001238',) ('FA200513652',) ('000614400967',)]
```

I'm wanting to take this list and attach it to a separate query

**the problem:**

```
query = "SELECT ItemLookupCode,Description, Quantity, Price, LastReceived "
query = query+"FROM Item "
query = query+"WHERE ItemLookupCode IN ("+skuArray+") " 
query = query+"ORDER BY LastReceived ASC;"
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

My guess here is that I need to format the string as:

```
'000381001238', '000381001238', '000381001238', 'FA200513652','000614400967'
```

**Ultimately** the string needs to read:

```
query = query+"WHERE ItemLookupCode IN ('000381001238', '000381001238', '000381001238', 'FA200513652','000614400967') "
```

I have tried the following:

```
skuArray = ''.join(skuArray.split('(', 1))
skuArray = ''.join(skuArray.split(')', 1))
```

Second Try:

```
skus = [sku[0] for sku in skuArray]
stubs = ','.join(["'?'"]*len(skuArray))


msconn = pymssql.connect(host=r'*', user=r'*', password=r'*', database=r'*')
cur = msconn.cursor()
query ='''
SELECT ItemLookupCode,Description, Quantity, Price, LastReceived
FROM Item 
WHERE ItemLookupCode IN { sku_params }
ORDER BY LastReceived ASC;'''.format(sku_params = stubs)
cur.execute(query, params=skus)
row = cur.fetchone()
print row[3]
cur.close()
msconn.close()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: don't format variables into SQL-Statements. Use placeholders.

Comment: Yeah, I do realize the SQL injection aspect.. I'll give that shot. Thanks!

Comment: "and the output is this" Are you sure? That does not look like the usual Python representation for either a tuple or a list. Looks more like a tuple of one-elemented tuples, but not exactly... Please show the _exact_ output, with all the brackets and commas, and possibly also tell us what `type(skuArray)` shown.

Comment: yes. that was output when I printed the list.

Comment: Also, why am I getting downvoted? I thought I asked this question well.. any advice here?

Comment: `"""select ItemLookupCode,Description, Quantity, Price, LastReceived
from item where ItemLookupCode in {} order by LastReceived ASC;""".format(tuple(x for x in skuArray))`.

Comment: @hinteractive02 you're welcome. The answers provided below work just as well. Please don't forget to upvote them.

Comment: Please correct your `skuArray` , it is NOT a valid python list.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do the straight inline SQL you could use a list comprehension:

```
', '.join(["'{}'}.format(sku[0]) for sku in skuArray])
```

Note: You need to add commas between tuples (based on example)

That said, if you want to do some sql, I would encourage you to parameterize your request with ?

Here is an example of how you would do something like that:

```
skuArray = [('000381001238',), ('000381001238',), ('000381001238',), ('FA200513652',), ('000614400967',)]
skus = [sku[0] for sku in skuArray]
stubs = ','.join(["'?'"]*len(skuArray))

qry = '''
SELECT ItemLookupCode,Description, Quantity, Price, LastReceived 
FROM Item 
WHERE ItemLookupCode IN ({ sku_params })
ORDER BY LastReceived ASC;'''.format(sku_params = stubs)

#assuming pyodbc connection syntax may be off
conn.execute(qry, params=skus)
```

Why?

Non-parameterized queries are a bad idea because it leaves you vulnerable to sql injection and is easy to avoid.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks again - However I get an error because there is no second comma: ('000381001238',),  any ideas here?

Comment: Edit: I have updated my question with this code (cleaner)

Comment: Do you need to have it as a tuple or can you just straight value search?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Traceback.. ", line 60, in <module>
    ORDER BY LastReceived ASC;'''.format(sku_params = stubs)
KeyError: ' sku_params '

Comment: the query just needs to read: ItemLookupCode IN ('000381001238', '0003810453534', '00033453457') etc..

Comment: `?` have to be used without the `'`.

Comment: Sorry, am a bit sidetracked at work.  You n eed the single quotes otherwise the params will just be injected.  You'll get "IN x y z foo... OH, it might be the parens....

Comment: Tried removing the `'` .. no luck thanks for your help though Error: `traceback line 59, in <module>
    ORDER BY LastReceived ASC;'''.format(sku_params = stubs)
KeyError: ' sku_params '`

Comment: You need the apostrophe, one thing you should do to debug is print out the entire statement (print query) and see if you can drop in the arguments and see if it looks right/runs.  That will solve your issue most likely

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `skuArray` is a list, like this:

```
>>> skuArray = [('000381001238',), ('000381001238',), ('000381001238',), ('FA200513652',), ('000614400967',)]
```

You can format your string like this:

```
>>> ', '.join(["'{}'".format(x[0]) for x in skuArray])
"'000381001238', '000381001238', '000381001238', 'FA200513652', '000614400967'"
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that `skuArray` is a list.

Comment: Yes, this is a list. Thank you.